# How to access a variable value that is defined inside another function JS

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I have a variable totalActivatedOffers which is defined inside a function, inside an IF statement. I need to be able to use the value of this variable outside of the IF statement by another function but can't get it to work, it keeps returning undefined.

I've declared it at the top of the script block like this:

```
var totalActivatedOffers;
```

But still no joy. Here is an example of how the value is assigned to it (simplified for illustration):

```
if ("SSO" in sessionStorage) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (firstArrayLength.length == 3) {
      var totalActivatedSparksOffers = 4;
    }
    if (secondArrayLength.length == 3) {
      var totalActivatedRewardsOffers = 7;
    }
    var totalActivatedOffers = totalActivatedSparksOffers + totalActivatedRewardsOffers;
  }, 2500) 
} // closes if SSO is inside session storage

// need to access the value here, outside of the IF statement
console.log('Total activated offers to subtract is ' + totalActivatedOffers);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SOLUTION:

Managed to get around the issue by making it a window variable like this:

```
window.totalActivatedOffers = totalActivatedSparksOffers + totalActivatedRewardsOffers;
```

Comment: If you want to access a global variable, don't re-declare it locally!

Comment: Note that the code after the `if` won't wait for the timeout, so it will log the value of `totalActivatedOffers` before the timeout function changes it, even if you fix the variable declarations.

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed to solve the issue by making it a window variable

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue by making it a window variable:

```
window.totalActivatedOffers = totalActivatedSparksOffers + totalActivatedRewardsOffers;
```